# Low hit question because of low-hit language tag usage, considering using Java next time

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977194/one-off-object-pooling-with-actor-provider) which I initially ill-tagged as being, among others, a *java* question. A user quite rightfully replaced that tag with the much less popular but more accurate *jvm* tag.

In the first few minutes, while the question bore the *java* tag, the question received 5 hits, while after the tag correction its hit rate got down to almost zero, receiving only 40 hits over the following two days.

I wrote the code in *Scala* because that's the language I use for most of my code, but I could have equally written the same code and question with plain *Java* and get many more hits and, presumably, more quality answers.

Should I be strategic and use Java just because of the higher exposure this would get my question ? It's unlikely I would use Java for my own code, but I am considering communicating in Java, just as I don't use my mother tongue for communication over the Internet, for precisely the same reason.

Comment: Get rid of one of the other tags and put Java back on it.

Comment: Not all Java experts are Scala experts. It's like Android and Java. A Java expert who has never touched Android will sometime ask redundant clarification comment which an Android expert won't in a question tagged both Java and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are here so that you can properly categorize your question. If you can properly justify using a given tag, then use it. I don't use Java or Scala, but if Java is related to Scala, and users who write code in Java are likely to know what you're talking about, I don't see a reason *not* to use it.

That being said, if your question has *absolutely nothing* to do with Java, it's not appropriate to use the tag.

I like to think that it's a best-judgement sort of thing. This site was made primarily so that people with less experience coding something can connect with people who have more experience coding that something. If this enhances your ability to properly connect with the **correct** people, then it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use the Java tag for this. As someone who knows Java and not Scala, I'm not exactly sure what your question is about and a lot of the hits probably didn't either. While you could use Java, you didn't and apart from 4 keywords it's unrecognisable as such.

But **hits aren't really that important, answers are**, and you got two. I think it's much more likely that people saw the 2 very thorough answers and didn't have anything further to add, or as you haven't commented on them yet, assumed you haven't checked whether those answers were right and wanted to see if they are before they suggest something else.

**tl;dr** Do whatever you like but it may get re-tagged again and you should reply to the existing answers so people know those answers are wrong and you're still there and expecting another answer.

Comment: Then perhaps it was my question being too specifically framed. Using actors and Scala really had nothing to do with the core question of an asynchronous heavy-object spawner. You may be right about the 40 persons having seen the question having nothing further to add; that's why I will use Java next time.